# CSS List-Items Not Displaying Below Each Other

Tags: jquery, css, list

I have spent the last 3 days creating a menu structure which is generated from a database. It works perfectly with the exception of my styling of my List-items. I have coloured the background of the problem area in Red, and these areas show when you hover over the words

> Bus Stops
>    Employees
>    Fences
>    Vehicles

The list-items within these red boxes are displaying alongside each other rather than vertically below each other. I cannot for the life of me work out why?

I have created a fiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/tMYxT/4/

I have also set the background color to Red in the Javascript section to help show where the hover event is occurring, and save any good Samaritan the time of searching the code.

Please someone help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because of your CSS.

When you declare

```
#navigation li, .headerRight li { margin: 4px 7px 4px 2px; padding: 0px; float: left; background-color: Transparent; }
```

you're telling the browser to float left all of the  li's under navigation until you tell it otherwise.

```
#navigation .submenu .submenu li {
   float:none;
}
```

will tell it not to float on all the list items when their in a second level submenu.

Comment: Marvelous. Thanks for that Knollbert! Strange as I applied that CSS change from the JS, in the same place I set the BGColor to red, but it didn't take. Lastly then, do you know how I would get the absolute positioned level 2 menu, to detect its width and height according to its content. As you may see the content is not remaining within its content area. Thanks Devin

Comment: Hey @user1434739, just wondering why you didn't accept my correct answer as it was posted well before Knollberts?

Answer (score 2):

If you add this line to the end of your css file it'll stop those ones floating left:

```
#navigation .submenu li .submenu li {
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Billy, but Knollbert already answered it. The remaining problem I am having then is how to get the absolute positioned level 2 menu, to detect its width and height according to its content inside. As you may see the content is not remaining within its content area on the 4 submenu's. If you can help that would be great. I have updated the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/tMYxT/7/    ...Thanks Devin

Comment: Yeah, but what I was saying was that I answered it BEFORE Knollbert did. No big deal, it's just that preffered form on Stackoverflow is to accept the best correct answer that was posted first. You should post your second query as a new question.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see it. Also, if I am not misunderstood, his CSS selector is cleaner. I shall post a new question. Thanks again though :)

Answer (score 1):

Your css is a mess. Let's clean it.

First of all let's clear the floats

```
#logo,#currentPage {
    clear:both;
}
.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}
#headerDiv:after, #navigation:after{
    content: '';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Then, if your submenu has `position:absolute` then the parent `li` should have `position:relative`

```
.headerLeft li {
    position: relative;
}
```

Remove the `height` from `header, #headerDiv`.

Here is what I have now - [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tMYxT/9/). So, how do you expect it to be?

Comment: Hi Alexander. No the layout as I had it was correct. The only remaining issue is  how to get the absolute positioned level 2 menu, to detect its width and height according to its content inside. As you may see the content is not remaining within its content area on the 4 submenu's. If you can help that would be great. I have updated the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/devin85/tMYxT/7 ...Thanks Devin

Comment: You can simply use `white-space: nowrap;` for `li` elements.